# Get Xamarin toolchain version information from command line

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, continuous-integration, xbuild, mdtool

I want to ensure that the correct version of mdtool, mono, the sdk and xamarin.android/ios is installed on  our CI environment. For that, my idea is to add a version check in the Jenkins/Ant Buildprocess which prevents the build from executing, if the correct version is not installed.

I can receive [all the relevant information from xamarin studio](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/beginning_a_xamarin_trial/Images/starter.png), but how do I get the same thing from the command line? Neither xbuild, nor mdtool provide me with a version. If I start a build with mdtool, the most relevant thing that comes up is this here:

```
build-android:
     [echo] Building for android
     [exec] XBuild Engine Version 3.2.6.0
     [exec] Mono, Version 3.2.6.0
     [exec] Copyright (C) Marek Sieradzki 2005-2008, Novell 2008-2011.
```

Is there a way to receive the complete version information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Xamarin.iOS you can run:

`$ /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mtouch --version`

and that will output something like:

> mtouch 8.5.0.122 (107d1ad)

which is the version of Xamarin.iOS which shipped the `mtouch` command.

You can get something similar for Xamarin.Android using:

`$ /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mandroid --version
mandroid 4.16.0.44545666 Business`

Comment: Thank you so much, works awesome! The only thing is that for me, `mtouch` is located here: `/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch --version`

Comment: You might be using an older version of XI. The location was changed a few releases back (7.4). http://developer.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_7/xamarin.ios_7.4/